# Need listbox with multiple selection - in yii

Tags: yii, html-select, yii-chtml

I need listbox of multiple selection in yii, i have code of form area
but its saving to database as a word "Array" in field, How to handle
this problem?

how to get back while view and update and grid view also

```
<?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'clients', 
  CHtml::listData(client::model()->findAll(array('order'=>'id')), 'id', 'name'),
     array('empty'=>'','multiple'=>'multiple','style'=>'width:400px;','size'=>'10'));
?>
```

Thank you.

Comment: It is being saved in the database as array because multiple select will return an array. Loop through the array to extract the values and then save them accordingly, either as multiple entries or as comma separated values

Answer (score 3):

For me works this:

```
'multiple'=>true
```

Your code must be something like that:

```
<?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'clients', 
  CHtml::listData(client::model()->findAll(array('order'=>'id')), 'id', 'name'),
     array('empty'=>'','multiple'=>true ,'style'=>'width:400px;','size'=>'10'));
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$htmlOptions = array('size' => '5', 'multiple' => 'true','style'=>'width: 333px');

$model->field_id    =   array_of_data_to_be_selected

$form->listBox($model,'field_id',$listData, $htmlOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is a relation you may want to use this : http://yiiext.github.com/activerecord-relation-behavior/ which takes care of saving array into many to many relation junction table.

Otherwise, like Orlymee said, you need to save each item of the array by looping through it or you can serialize the array or implode it into comma separated values and do the reverse of whatever method you chose to save, while viewing.

Answer (score 0):

keep this code in controller

```
$arr = implode(",",$model->attributes['hobbies']);

$model->hobbies=$arr;
```

in controler create,update in the first if condition

in database you can see the values with comma as delimiter

Comment: Thanks for your answers, My major problem is int he view/_form page, how i can re-select back while update. because all the values are separated by commas, i can explode it also no issue, but, i dont know how i can re-select automatically while update..

Answer (score 0):

How does this work in CHtml::listBox()

```
if(!empty($htmlOptions['multiple']))
{
    if(substr($name,-2)!=='[]')
        $name.='[]';
}
```

So you can try this

```
<?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'clients', 
    CHtml::listData(client::model()->findAll(array('order'=>'id')), 'id', 'name'),
    array(
>>>     'name'=>CHtml::resolveName($model, 'clients').'[]',
        'empty'=>'',
        'multiple'=>'multiple',
        'style'=>'width:400px;',
        'size'=>'10',
    )
);?>
```

But it's better to use CHtml::listBox()