# Selecting Multiple values in CHtml::dropdownlist yii

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, yii

I have dropdownlist as

```
echo CHtml::dropDownList('personids', '',$list, array('id'=>'sea'.$dd,'class'=>'vulntr-textfld1','prompt'=>'Select',));
```

and the list data is

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->addCondition('PersonTypeCode=:PersonTypeCode AND FamilyId=:FamilyId ');
$criteria->params=array(':PersonTypeCode'=>$category,':FamilyId'=>$Familyid);
$lookupval = Person::model()->findAll($criteria);
$list = CHtml::listData($lookupval, 'PersonID', 'FirstName');
```

it is working well..but my question is how to select multiple values in this dropdownlist , please any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10740877/need-listbox-with-multiple-selection-in-yii

Comment: thank you for reply, checked it but that didnt work well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use a Yii Extension for selecting multiple dropdown values.. The name of extension is "Select2"

Extension Details **[Here](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/select2/)**

Download link for **[Select2](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/select2/files/select2-20130215.zip)**

Extract the downloaded file to your application extensions directory

For selecting multiple values.. You should add `htmlOptions` to select multiple values.

`$list` will be an array that you have send to this code.

```
$this->widget('ext.select2.ESelect2',array(
  'name'=>'anything',
  'data'=>$list,
  'htmlOptions'=>array(
    'multiple'=>'multiple',
  ),
));
```

Comment: cant we do anything without any extension..?

Comment: Not really, thats why they have made extension, Its the easiest way to do.. Maybe there are some other extension too. but Select2 is best one, I have used it.

Comment: thq , above  extension works fine but i want to have checkboxes to select in dropdownlist rather than selecting horizontal

Comment: I think there is another one for checkboxes, i have not used it but you can try looking for Bootstrap MultiSelect with jquery. https://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/